# update-alternatives: error: alternative path /lib/plymouth/themes/MIB-Ubuntu/MIB-Ubuntu.plymouth doesn't exist

Tags: software-center, software-installation

When I try to download some software from Ubuntu center or from Synaptic, I get package operation failed...

[image: Package operation failed via Ubuntu Software Center]

How to fix this?

edit:

I tried to install this game:

[image]

This is the details from the installation:

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously deselected package libbulletml0d2.
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 239257 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libbulletml0d2 (from .../libbulletml0d2_0.0.6-4_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package tumiki-fighters-data.
Unpacking tumiki-fighters-data (from .../tumiki-fighters-data_0.2.dfsg1-4_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package tumiki-fighters.
Unpacking tumiki-fighters (from .../tumiki-fighters_0.2.dfsg1-4_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.UTF8.cache...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Setting up plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu (0.5.0-2) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /lib/plymouth/themes/MIB-Ubuntu/MIB-Ubuntu.plymouth doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libbulletml0d2 (0.0.6-4) ...
Setting up tumiki-fighters-data (0.2.dfsg1-4) ...
Setting up tumiki-fighters (0.2.dfsg1-4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu
Setting up plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu (0.5.0-2) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /lib/plymouth/themes/MIB-Ubuntu/MIB-Ubuntu.plymouth doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Comment: What happens when you press "Details" Could you edit your post to include the output from it?

Comment: @Marco Ceppi I added the "details" from the installation...

Comment: Looks like Plymouth isnt working right, or the theme that is being used doesnt exist. Sounds like a glitch in `plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu`

Comment: And the fix for this is... ?

Answer (score 5):

This will work, at least for me:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu
```

If not, try this:

```
sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu
```

After that, you can re-install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu
```

And make sure all package are fine with this check:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I currently using Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 LTS, with Kernel 2.6.38.

Answer (score 3):

Not a guarantee to work, but this is worth a shot; drop a shell Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will attempt to fix any package dependencies after the failure of a given package. Has bailed me out about 90% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this isn't a problem at all. Why? I have been getting this error quite a few times, and it is NOT a problem in installation. It is simply an error which the system gives out while updating the Library.

I usually just ignored the problem, because the application that I downloaded was already installed. Search it on your system, I can bet that it has already been installed.

Otherwise, use the code:

> sudo apt-get --purge remove plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu

Works for me, although I lose the MIB Plymouth theme, which I don't even use now. Big Deal!

Answer (score 0):

From the details of the installation it is clear that you are missing the alternative paths for plymouth-theme-mib-ubuntu as seen on line 18.

update-alternatives: error: alternative path /lib/plymouth/themes/MIB-Ubuntu/MIB-Ubuntu.plymouth doesn't exist.

What I did to correct this was create the said path.

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/plymouth/themes/MIB-Ubuntu/MIB-Ubuntu.plymouth
```