# Can't remove package

Tags: apt, dpkg

I guess I removed some files that package `jetty` required because when I try to remove it with `apt-get remove jetty` I get this:

```
Removing jetty ...
 * jetty is not installed
invoke-rc.d: initscript jetty, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing jetty (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
 * jetty is not installed
invoke-rc.d: initscript jetty, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jetty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So how can I remove it?

Comment: Try apt-get purge jetty

Comment: No, it ain't working.

Comment: This answer from Ringtail worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/106918/240973.

Comment: @terdon both questions are different

Comment: @Braiam the OP solved this using the answer from that question.

Comment: @terdon I would rewrite the answer here, instead because if you read the error they are different, no?

Comment: @Braiam not really, no. Both are errors of the post-installation script. Anyway, if you think that duplicating the information is useful, go ahead.