# Hi i cannot download anything from the software center nor can i get my updates to install, i get this error

Tags: software-center, update-manager

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (9: Bad file descriptor)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
david@david-Inspiron-N5110:~$
```

Comment: I would suggest you do a df to see whether the /var directory is on a disk partition that's full. If so, then you will need to do some clean up. Otherwise Amir's answer should help you in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to askUbuntu ;)

open up your terminal (ctrl+alt+t) or you can find it using the superkey (the windowskey in windows) and then write terminal. In terminal first write:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

then hit enter. a password prompt will be showed up, enter password and hit enter. Afterward run the update manager in terminal via:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and hit enter. wait for the packages to be upgraded and updated.

**EDITED/Added: Thanks to @Alexis Wilke** : First check the /var partition of your hard whether its full or not. Do it using terminal with the command :

```
df -h
```

if so, clean up some space and the retry ;)

Hope that works ;)

Comment: It is still not working, I get the same error again and again. I am new to ubuntu so I dont really know anything about it

Comment: i get an error saying i cant open /var/lib/dpkg/status and now the software center is not opening either

Comment: @dividas, check the updated answer

Comment: I have upgraded to ubuntu 13.04 and now i cant get any software to download from the software center it gives me this error

Comment: installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package libnss3-1d:amd64.

Comment: @davidas, take a look at here : [Same Issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54851/package-operation-failed-when-installing-software)